# How to implement "CanRaiseEvent" property in VB6?

Tags: vb6

Reference Link to "CanRaiseEvent" property: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.canraiseevents?view=netframework-4.8#System_Windows_Forms_Control_CanRaiseEvents

Given that events in VB6 are recursive, I would like to disable a given controls event, while in a event handler sub.

For example, currently, if in a TextBox change event the contents of the TextBox are changed (say to "test") another event will fire causing the state of the current event to be stacked and the TextBox change event will be called again. I can prevent the event from repeating the code with a simple "If" (e.g. If Text1.Text = "test" Then Exit Sub). This will immediately exit the second event and return to the state of the first event to continue processing.  However, I would prefer to disable the TextBox event on entering the initial event. It would appear that the property cited in the reference link would accomplish this, but it is not recognized by VB6.

Is there something I need to declare first to use the "CanRaiseEvent" property in VB6?

Thanks X

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it kind of like this, but it might not be worth the ffort.  (And by the way, I don't have the VB6 IDE on this PC so this will be un-syntax checked but it should get you started.

Within your Form (and for this example let's say the textbox you care about is txtFirstName):

```
Private WithEvents mFirstNameEventListener As Textbox

Private Sub mFirstNameEventListener_TextChanged() 'or whatever the event is called in VB6
   DisableEvents

   'do work here, like forcing to upper-case etc

   EnableEvents
End Sub

Sub Form_Load()
   EnableEvents
End Sub

Sub Form_Unload()
   DisableEvents
End Sub


Private Sub EnableEvents()
   Set mFirstNameEventListener = txtFirstName
End Sub

Private Sub DisableEvents()
   Set mFirstNameEventListener = Nothing
End Sub
```

Also note, you would not use the standard VB6 stubbed out event handler too.  you would only do it this way.  (Otherwise both event handlers would get called)

Comment: Sorry I didn't see your reply sooner. Looks like your creating your own textbox event. Are you assigning the name of an existing textbox with                                                
 Set mFirstNameEventListener = txtFirstName to your created event?

Comment: Well the text box creates the event, I just outlined how to listen for it, and stop listening, manually.

Comment: It still looks like your event, preempts the stock textbox event.  I thought that's what you meant when you stated "you would not use the standard VB6 stubbed out event handler too".

Comment: Ah, I understand your question. If you define the stock event handler (txtfirstname_Textchange) using the VB6 IDE as normal then BOTH the manual event listener and the stock one will fire.  So simply skip defining the stock one.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way this is done is with a `Static ... Boolean` variable:

```
   Sub SomeEvent
     Static inHere As Boolean

     If inHere Then 
        Exit Sub
     Else
        inHere = True
     End If
        .....
     inHere = False
   End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but your approach is essentially the same as my example "If" statement; it doesn't avoid the recursion. The only way to avoid the recursion is to disable the event from within the event handler. And, I afraid the link I supplied is only valid for Net components, not VB6.

Comment: Yes, VB6 doesn't have what you want so you have to do something else. You can't avoid the recursion but you can short-circuit it as I showed. Your approach is vaguely similar but the boolean test is fast and generic.

Comment: @Xytsrm this answer is correct. Your reference is for .NET and VB6 predates .NET entirely, so CanRaiseEvent is irrelevant / nonexistant. Using a static is one approach, another pattern is to use a module or form-level variable to allow disabling multiple events.

Comment: I've checked the Win32 API functions and, as yet, have not found an API that might be used to suspend a given controls event. Does, anyone know of an API, or perhaps a hidden control property accessible via "SetWindowLong"?